# BSP deployment API

Tags: web-deployment, sap-bsp

I'm trying to find some documentation about publish\updating a BSP project (Reactjs build in my case, which works like a charm) via Web API.

That way I could automate build\deploy via Atlassian Bamboo, avoiding long and exhausting manual procedures for the SAP transaction (`SE38`).

Can't really find anything related to my goal, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I could use Jenkins if there's nothing for Bamboo.

Comment: Unlikely you will find such product. What do you imply under `long and exhausting manual procedures for the SE38`?

Comment: I would like to be able to automate deploy BSP project. Coming from continuous integration servers like Jenkins or Bamboo, I'm used to deploy via maximum one click.

Comment: Deployment in SAP usually means activation. What concrete troubles do you have during deployment?